# How to retrieve transport infrastructure data from Google Map?

Tags: google-maps, osm2pgsql

I imported into Postgis OSM data using `Osm2pgsql`. My objective was to get a database with roads elements for a specific region of Italy (i.e. traffic lights, driving directions and turning direction at junction). However there are a lot of missing data, because almost all the cells are empty. I would like to know if I did something wrong and if there is an alternative way to obtain these data. For instance I would like to know if there exists a way to retrieve data from Google map (transport infrastructure or even  real time traffic information)?

Comment: The only public Google Transit feed for Italy is Torino http://code.google.com/p/googletransitdatafeed/wiki/PublicFeeds

Comment: yes, there is a way to import data from google maps using a software called arcgis, I don't how its done but I know for sure is possible with that software.